# My epoch time in syslog is 8 hours behind. How do I fix it?

Tags: centos, syslog

I am in the PST (UTC -8) timezone. My syslog in stamping all messages as PST -8 instead of UTC, or even UTC -8 (so the timestamps are 8 hours behind my local time!).

- regular date command is correct as expected

  - My ACTUAL current local time:

```bsh
[user@pc]$date
Fri Feb  7 17:09:42 PST 2020
```

- a sample syslog log message:

```bsh
fluent-bit    | [0] logs.syslog.pc: [1581095382.000000000,
```

- that epoch date is wrong; the conversion makes it clear to see it's wrong:

```bsh
[user@pc]$ date -d @1581095382.000000000
Fri Feb  7 09:09:42 PST 2020
```

- NTP is set and corrext

```bsh
[admin@devatomic88 bitnami-docker-fluent-bit]$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Fri 2020-02-07 17:09:42 PST
  Universal time: Sat 2020-02-08 01:09:42 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2020-02-08 01:09:42
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PST, -0800)
```

How do I fix that?